# javascript checking if a checkbox is disabled by input value

Tags: javascript

I am using a `checkbox` to show additional fields in a form.

This `checkbox` will be only be enabled if the `DROPDOWN` has `selectedIndex > 0`

It is working very fine. The problem lies when the user use the `BACK Button` on the browser.

The `checkbox` will be disabled because it reads `selectedIndex = 0` but the value is still there.

and its has attribute `disbaled="disabled"`

I know the `selectedIndex` was 0 because I used javascript

```
init(){
   var a = document.getElementById('ddList').selectedIndex;

   alert(a);
}

document.onload = init();
```

**PROBLEM:**
When back button is used, the dropdown value is retained, the checkbox is checked, but it is disabled.

I hope it is somehow clear to the readers.

Comment: I don't think that `init` function is write unless you missed copying `function`. Either way its `document.onload = init`

Comment: well it still loads and messagebox shows up. but the problem I am asking is different.

Comment: sure thats because of how braces work though

Comment: did you try `document.onload = init;`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: yes, that is not my problem here. my problem is that, the checkbox is getting disabled where it was enabled before, when the BACK button is used. I think its because i used the { disabled="disabled" } in the checkbox.

Comment: HTML is stateless, what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is doing what you want

The function? (if it is a function) `init` is called immediately when you write

```
document.onload = init();
```

As this will call `init()` and set `document.onload` to the return of init - which will be `undefined`.

So your code is running before the document is actually ready and the selected index is actually set. I believe that is your problem.

Change the code to:

```
function init(){
   var a = document.getElementById('ddList').selectedIndex;

   alert(a);
} 
document.onload = init;//call init on load
```

Answer (score 0):

I used body onload instead.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

it waits for the values to fillup instead of document.onload